# There was no endpoint listening at (url)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF service which generates an error when the method of service is being called. I have tried a lot of topics on internet and none of them has helped me so far. What am I doing wrong?

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at (url) that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

```
Dim serviceClient As New DataServiceClient
Dim cls As New ClsDataAccess
Dim dt As New DataTable()

Dim json As String = DataTableToJson(dt)
Dim string1 As String = Convert.ToString(serviceClient.UsersList(json))
```

Comment: put your client statements too, please

Comment: The error changed. What client statements do you mean? I edited the question.

Comment: It's may be you have two client method (like jquery ajax)that first one on server side redirect you to other page and second method can't find current position to continue. Or any action like this that your code lost its position

Comment: As the error says, most likely there is no service available at the URL you are using.   Either its not running, the address is wrong or it couldn't start.  Post the service and client config files, please.

Comment: The service is running on the server. I'll post the service and client config files